# What is the difference between "buy something at shop," "in a shop" and "from a shop"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in meaning between *buy something at a shop*, *in a shop* or *from a shop*? For example:

> I bought the phone **at** the shop on the next street.
>
> I bought the phone **in** the shop on the next street.
>
> I bought the phone **from** the shop on the next street.

I feel that the sentences basically mean the same, but I cannot see the slight difference. If there is not none, then which preposition is the most common in the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that they are relatively interchangeable sentences.

The first (**at**) is most common and reads like it focuses more on what the shop was than the fact you physically entered its doors.

The second (**in**) has a little bit more focus on the fact that you went inside the store to make your purchase.

The last (**from**) is a bit ambiguous as to whether you physically went to the store or may have ordered on line or phoned them to place the order.